# Unable to resolve NULL driver for [Illuminate\Mail\TransportManager]. in laravel 6 driver smto gmail

Tags: laravel-6

this my .env config

```
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

[image]

does anyone have a solution?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think you get value from .env file but the value was not got.I just
>   suggest first confirm your parameter was got value or not by using
>   TINKER.

```
php artisan tinker
```

and check by 
env('MAIL_PASSWORD')

> If you don't got the value then try to clear cache by using given
>   commanad.

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

and then try again with tinker.